# Vue use Pinia store in helper functions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I have a Vue.js app, and I want to create a few helper functions that will use a Pinia store that I have in the app. These helper functions will be used by multiple components. How do I do this? Do I define helper functions in the store file itself? Do I create a plain js file that depends on a Pinia store?

Comment: [Using a store outside of a component](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html).  helper functions can go in their own js file.  import `useStore` composable into the file but be sure to only call it from _within_ a helper function. As long as the helper functions are not called before the pinia instance is initialized, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I created index.js or route.js in the src/stores folder and used the following code to import the store in my component

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useStore = defineStore({
  state: () => ({
  }),
  getters: {
  },
  actions: {
  },
});
```

and using in component

```
import { useStore } from '@/stores';
```

I hope this helps